# PHP how to Whileloop through a while loop

Tags: php

I am very new to PHP i have illustrated my issue below

I already use a while-loop to fetch pupils that have the same parent in pupil table

My question here is how do I use result from  the looped class_id above (pupil table) to loop through and fetch result from class_id in fee table

see image for clear illustration

[image]

```
    <?php 

    $sql3= "select * from pupil where parent=$parent_get";
    $runsql3=mysqli_query($mycon,$sql3) or die ("no connection");


    while($getpupils3=mysqli_fetch_array($runsql3)){
    $sid=$getpupils3["id"];
    $sname=$getpupils3["name"];
    $sclass=$getpupils3["class_id"];

    $sql = "Select * from class where id = $sclass";
        $runquery = $mycon->query($sql);
        if($runquery->num_rows > 0){
            $fetchdata=mysqli_fetch_array($runquery);
            $c_name=$fetchdata['name'];
            $c_title=$fetchdata['title'];
            $class_info=$c_name.' '.$c_title;
        }

    $sql4= "select * from fee where class=$sclass AND term=$term_get AND session=$session_get";
    $runsql4=mysqli_query($mycon,$sql4) or die ("no connection");
    while($getpupils4=mysqli_fetch_array($runsql4)){    
        $fee_title=$getpupils4["fee_title"];
        $fee_amount=$getpupils4["fee_amount"];
        $fee_des=$getpupils4["fee_des"];

        echo'
                            <div class="col-lg-4">
                                <div class="card m-b-30 card-body">
                                    <h4 class="card-title font-20 mt-0">'.$sname.'</h4>
                                    <p class="card-text">'.$class_info.'</p>
                                    <p class="card-text">'.$fee_title.': '.$fee_amount.'</p>
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light">Edit</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
  ';}}?>
```

Comment: what's the result right now?

Comment: You could do all of this in SQL, which will be MUCH more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to echo the first part of the html for the pupil before the while loop for the fees, and the bottom of the pupil html after the while loop.

```
<?php 
$sql3= "select * from pupil where parent=$parent_get";
$runsql3=mysqli_query($mycon,$sql3) or die ("no connection");
while($getpupils3=mysqli_fetch_array($runsql3)){
    $sid=$getpupils3["id"];
    $sname=$getpupils3["name"];
    $sclass=$getpupils3["class_id"];

    $sql = "Select * from class where id = $sclass";
    $runquery = $mycon->query($sql);
    if($runquery->num_rows > 0){
        $fetchdata=mysqli_fetch_array($runquery);
        $c_name=$fetchdata['name'];
        $c_title=$fetchdata['title'];
        $class_info=$c_name.' '.$c_title;
    }
    // output the pupil details before the fee while loop
    echo'<div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="card m-b-30 card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title font-20 mt-0">'.$sname.'</h4>
            <p class="card-text">'.$class_info.'</p>';

    $sql4= "select * from fee where class=$sclass AND term=$term_get AND session=$session_get";
    $runsql4=mysqli_query($mycon,$sql4) or die ("no connection");
    $fee_total = 0;
    while($getpupils4=mysqli_fetch_array($runsql4)){    
        $fee_title=$getpupils4["fee_title"];
        $fee_amount=$getpupils4["fee_amount"];
        $fee_des=$getpupils4["fee_des"];
        // output the fee detail
        echo '<p class="card-text">'.$fee_title.': '.$fee_amount.'</p>';
        // increment the fee total
        $fee_total += $fee_amount;
    }
    // output the fee total
    echo '<p class="card-text">Total '.$fee_total.'</p>';
    // output the bottom of the box after the fee while loop
    echo '<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light">Edit</a>
        </div>
    </div>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much Tristan You are a messiah.!!!  Pls can you show how i can sum up the total of all  $fee_amount generated for the loop. Thanks

Comment: @Fola see the updated answer. You may want to use `Total $'.number_format($fee_total,2).'` depending on your currency

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. i am left with no option than to look up to you again. The solution for the total fee came handy for each category in the group. But how do i calculate together all the totals generated from each. Thanks  See https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELb3p.png

Comment: @Fola use the same logic by setting a variable outside the first while loop and incrementing it in the while loop